# .NET 5 Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, cors, .net-5

I'm currently trying to enable CORS on a .NET Core 5 API. Non-preflight, cross-origin requests work fine; however, all `OPTIONS` requests are resulting in the above message. My `Startup.cs` looks something like this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddCors(options =>
  {
    options.AddPolicy(corsPolicyName, builder =>
    {
      builder
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials();
    });
  });
  ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseCors(corsPolicyName);
  app.UseAuthorization();
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
  });
}
```

After looking through a few other threads, I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my configuration. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know you answered this yourself, but it would be helpful to see **a)** the controller that should handle the request and **b)** the request that you are making.

Answer (score 2):

Remove :

```
.AllowCredentials();
```

and move app.UseCors(corsPolicyName) between UseRouting and UseAuthorization:

```
  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(corsPolicyName);
  app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix my issue. Thank you for the suggestion though; I've updated my example to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling anonymous authentication on my API fixed the issue. `OPTIONS` requests don't include credentials so not allowing anonymous auth was causing them to be rejected.

Anonymous authentication can be enabled by going to the project's properties > Debug > Check "Enable Anonymous Authentication".